# netlogo: how to separate two armies in 4 corners?

Tags: netlogo

I have to do a program where two base fields are created for each of the two armies of agents that are going to meet. How do I put every army to its corners? Soldiers and generals are created for each army and have to be born in one of their corners aleatory. In what I have done, soldiers and generals are already created, but they are not being separated by the army. (I wanted to do [army 1] [army 2]).

```
breed [ soldiers soldier ]
soldiers-own [ army ]
breed [ generals general ]
generals-own [ army ]

globals [ converted-soldiers death-by-energy death-by-combat ] 

turtles-own[ energy max-energy ]

to setup
  clear-all
  setup-patches
  setup-turtles
  reset-ticks
end

to setup-patches
  set-patch-size 15

  ask patches[
  if (distancexy 20 20) < base-size [set pcolor yellow]
  if (distancexy -20 -20) < base-size [set pcolor yellow]

  if (distancexy -20 20) < base-size [set pcolor pink]
  if (distancexy 20 -20) < base-size [set pcolor pink]
  ]

end

to setup-turtles

  create-soldiers init-soldiers [
    set shape "person"
    set color red
    set energy init-energy
    set max-energy 100 
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor

    while [pcolor = black or pcolor = yellow]
    [setxy random-xcor random-ycor]
  ]


  create-generals init-generals [
    set shape "person"
    set color green
    set energy init-energy
    set max-energy 100 
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor

    while [pcolor = black or pcolor = pink]
    [setxy random-xcor random-ycor]
  ]

end
```